# How to effectively extract the unmatched character from a given string using regex in Java

Tags: java, regex, string

I have a requirement such that I should validate for a given string and also I should extract any unmatched character (if present) from that string.

A String is considered Valid if it has any combination and any sequence of

a-z A-Z 0-9 -/?:().,'+ CR LF WhiteSpace

I use regex to do the validation by using the expression 
^[a-zA-Z0-9/?:().,'+\r\n -]

```
public class RegEx {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String textToValidate="(+aBcD23456 lkmsdklm 1dfr435f:/?,.' \r\n)";
        Set<Character> failedCharacter = getUnMatchedCharacter(textToValidate);
       if(failedCharacter.isEmpty()){
            System.out.println("Valid String");
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("Given String contains invalid characters "+failedCharacter);
        }
    }

    public static Set<Character> getUnMatchedCharacter(String textToValidate){
        Set<Character> failedCharacter = new LinkedHashSet<Character>();
        Pattern regexPattern = Pattern.compile("^[a-zA-Z0-9/?:().,'+\r\n -]");
        char[] charArray = textToValidate.toCharArray();
        for (char character : charArray) {
            Matcher result = regexPattern.matcher(String.valueOf(character));
            if(!result.matches()){
                failedCharacter.add(character);
            }
        }
        return failedCharacter;
    }
}
```

Excepted Output are as follows

- Positive Case

  - Input : textToValidate="(+aBcD23456 lkmsdklm
    1dfr435f:/?,.' \r\n)";
  - Output : Valid String
- Negative Case

  - Input : textToValidate="(+aBcD23456 &*^%$#@!lkmsdklm 1dfr435f:/?,.' \r\n)";
  - Output : Given String contains invalid characters [&, *, ^, %, $, #, @, !]

Now the problem is I don't feel like the above solution (coding) is not efficient enough for the given requirement.

I tried doing regex-negation, mathcher.find(), mathcher.group() but I am not getting the desired output.

Any suggestion on how to improve the above code or is there any other way to  effectively extract the unmatched character from a given string using regex in Java.

Comment: add the `+` quantifier and the end of the string anchor `$`. or use a negated pattern to find if there's a character that is not an allowed character. Other thing, in a java string pattern you must use escaped backslashes.

Comment: @ Casimir et Hippolyte : can you show some example on how to do it. I tried doing the regex-negated pattern. But, unfortunately its dint for me. Also i used the^[a-zA-Z0-9/?:().,'+\r\n -]+$" as you mentioned earlier but I don't get the desired output

Comment: @Soleil , see my answer, it provides a simple way to achieve what you are wanting.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple function to give your desired results

```
private String validateString(String s){
        ArrayList invalidChars = new ArrayList();
        char[] ch = s.toCharArray();
        String output = "";
        for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++){
            if((Character.isLetter(ch[i]) || Character.isDigit(ch[i]))){
                output += ch[i];
            }else invalidChars.add(ch[i]);
        }
        if(invalidChars.size() > 0) return "Given String contains invalid characters: " + invalidChars.toString();
        else return "Given string is valid: " + output;

    }
```

using

`validateString("abc123!@#");`

will return

`"Given String contains invalid characters: [!, @, #]`

Comment: What about the special characters which I have mentioned in the post -/?:().,'+ CR LF WhiteSpace Character.isLetter() & Character.isDigit() will allow characters from other language which has a unicode representation. My requirement is only to allow a-zA-Z0-9-/?:().,'+ CR LF WhiteSpace